# Like Button Error "This page is either disabled or not visible to the current user."

Tags: facebook-like

A week ago, the "Like Button" in a page I'm developping stopped working, whether I use XFBML or social plugins, I get the same result.
When some one tries to click the Like Button, the get an error message, and the link says "This page is either disabled or not visible to the current user."

What couldit be?

Comment: This appears to be a Facebook bug. Here's [the bug report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19916). Last updated a week ago and they seem to be actively looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue recently. If you used the like button generator, this is what solved it for me: you have to have the exact same settings in your iframe and open graph data as you did when you first generated the like button. Not sure why, but this was the only way to get mine to work. I had changed to a different layout and size. Of course, the facebook linter is definitely helpful as well:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

Put the url into the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and that should clear the cache.  If it is still an issue, perhaps your link got blocked for spam.  What is the url?

Comment: I've put it in URL Linter before, and now oncemore, but the result keeps the same. How can I know if it's been blocked for spam? and How can I fix that?