# Page Cannot Be Liked with Facebook Like Button

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

On http://www.btandthetenants.com, every page can be liked except for the Photos section.  I use AJAX to change the current page's like button and the script performs perfectly on every page including this one.  However, if you try to click like on this page, it will immediately undo your action.  The code for the head's open graph (generated HTML if y) is:

```html
<meta property="og:site_name"            content="Brandon Taylor & The Tenants" />
<meta property="fb:admins"               content="100000142903767,1290840046" />
<meta property="fb:app_id"               content="162010397258435" />
<meta property="og:url"                  content="http://www.btandthetenants.com/photos" />
<meta property="og:title"                content='Brandon Taylor & The Tenants | Photos' />
<meta property="og:type"                 content="band" />
<meta property="og:image"                content="http://www.btandthetenants.com/img/gi.png" />
<meta property="og:description"          content="See all of Brandon Taylor & The Tenants' pictures streamed straight from their Facebook page." />
```

And the code for the dynamic like button:

```html
<div id="fb-like"><div class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" data-layout="box_count" data-send="false" data-width="35" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial" data-href="http://www.btandthetenants.com/photos"><span style="height: 62px; width: 45px; "><iframe id="f1603dc7e8" name="f11a7f8ffc" scrolling="no" style="overflow: hidden; height: 62px; width: 45px; border: none; " title="Like this content on Facebook." class="fb_ltr" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=162010397258435&channel_url=http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=5#cb=f1d41deae&origin=http://www.btandthetenants.com/f3e64780fc&domain=www.btandthetenants.com&relation=parent.parent&extended_social_context=false&font=arial&href=http://www.btandthetenants.com/photos&layout=box_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&send=false&show_faces=false&width=55"></iframe></span></div></div>
```

I'm sincerely stumped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the page returns when I try clicking the like button:

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"requires_login":false,"success":false,"already_connected":false,"is_admin":false,"show_error":true,"error_info":{"brief":"Cannot see this page","full":"This page is either disabled or not visible to the current user.","errorUri":"\/connect\/connect_to_node_error.php?title=Cannot+see+this+page&body=This+page+is+either+disabled+or+not+visible+to+the+current+user.&hash=AQCKE3RqZ24PrqLg"}}}
```

It appears to be a bug that has been reported [here](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19916). Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288770/like-button-error-this-page-is-either-disabled-or-not-visible-to-the-current-us) which reports the same problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what on the console do you use to see this?

Comment: I used Google Chrome's built-in developers tool. You can access it by pressing ctrl+shift+i. The network tab shows the details of the requests made.